# Troubleshooting "mongo not found" and "php_mongo.dll is not a win32 application" errors

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I have been trying to install mongo for over 6 hours now and still have not gotten it to work.  I am going to make this very detailed so that hopefully someone will help me get this working.

```
My local comp: HP laptop, Windows 7, 64 bit operating system

WAMP 2.2 which includes php 5.3.8 and apache 2.2.21 downloaded from wampserver.com
```

I have tried installing every combination of mangodb with no success.

I started by downloading the 64 bit download from mongos website.  It works fine when I use it from the command line shell but once I install the `php_mongo.dll` and use it from PHP I get the "mongo not found" error. Also, I checked my `php.ini` file and mongo is not loading in.  I checked the errors and saw "php_mongo.dll is not a win32 application".

I then tried installing a new `php_mongo.dll` that was vc9 since that is what my `php.ini` file says.  I still get the same problem, it works in when I use it from the command line but not in PHP.

I then deleted all of the mongo files and treid downloaded the 32 bit verson of mongo just to give it a try (my os is 64 bit).  Same thing, works in the command line shell but not in PHP.  I get the same errors as above.

My `php.ini` file looks like this:

```
System  Windows NT xxxxx-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition 
Service Pack 1) AMD64
Build Date  Sep 16 2011 21:25:01
Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x64
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--with-
pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-
oci8=C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-
oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_11_2\sdk,shared" "--disable-
debug-pack" "--disable-static-analyze"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20090626
PHP Extension   20090626
Zend Extension  220090626
Zend Extension Build    API220090626,TS,VC9
PHP Extension Build     API20090626,TS,VC9
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, 
string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, 
zlib.*
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Again, I have tried every combination of the download and I cannot get a connection from php.  Can someone please walk me through the download based on the above information of my system set up or point out what I am doing wrong?

I have tried the basic set up options from mongos site.  I have also spent hours of google and from other blogs I know there are some issues with 64 bit comps and there are many other people getting these same errors.  I can't seem to find an answer that works or that is detailed enough for a newbie to follow.

Thank you for any help.  I just don't know what to do at this point, I've been working on setting up mongo for over 6 hours.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you download the [extensions](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads) and put them in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext`.. Also i t hnk i saw people having issues a while back trying to get the 64bit version to run with 64bit WAMP. Use the 32bits to be safe. Also, get a *nix box with a package manager box ;-)

Comment: Of course i have downloaded the extension but thanks.  What is a nix box?

Comment: A '*nix box' is a server with linux/unix. In other words a useless advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after hours and hours of searching for an answer to my original question which was:

> I am running a 64 bit machine with a 64 bit wamp stack but mongodb will not work in 
>   wamp 64 bit, how do i get all this working?

I finally just uninstalled wamp 64 bit and downloaded wamp 32 bit onto my windows 64 bit machine.  I then downloaded the mongo 64 bit version and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

PHP driver for Mongo DB is not currently working for 64bit wamp (you can keep your OS 64bit).
Basically what you need to do:

1. install 32 bit WAMP
2. add PHP mongo driver "php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.4-vc9.dll", ts(thread safe) to php ext foldr
   download: https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html
3. rename "extension=php_mongo.dll" to "php_mongo.dll" and add extension=php_mongo.dll to php.ini in your server

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

My operating system is 32 bit Windows 7
I did the following to add the mongoDb extension into my php:
1. Used: https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html
2. Downloaded: php_mongo-1.5.1.zip and unzip the file which contains the binaries for different PHP versions.
3. Copy php_mongo-1.5.1-5.4-vc9.dll to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext as php_mongo.dll
4. Added the following line in php.ini
    extension=php_mongo.dll
5. Restart my wamp server
    Used localhost/?phpinfo=1 to see the installed extension. It works fine.

First I tried php_mongo-1.5.5.zip to do the same but it was not working then successfully configured with php_mongo-1.5.1.zip.

Cheers...